# Error handling with async/await and promises, n² ways to shoot yourself in the foot react native errors

Tags: javascript

how to send different error in the same function using this code :

```
function fails3() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            throw new Error();
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

Comment: Pass the error object to the `reject` function to reject the promise.

Comment: Not sure if this is an option but you can create your own type of error which contains whatever stuff you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use reject and pass whathever you want to it:

```
const myError = {
  error1: 'Error found',
  error2: 'Timeout Reached'
}

function fails3() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            reject(myError);
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

Once the promised is rejected, because the timeout was reached, the error will be thrown and you can catch it like:

```
function myFunction() {
  fails3()
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.error1)); // Handle error 
}
```

or if you prefer (who doesn't) async/await

```
async function myFunction() {
  try {
    await fails3();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.error2);  // Handle error
  }
}
```